# Can't set up Gmail Multiple Inbox

Tags: gmail

The rest of the guys in office are able to easily set up the lab app for their inbox called *Multiple Inbox*. I on the other hand seem to be doing something wrong.

How do I setup Google Multiple Inboxes so that 2-5 other Labels appear in my inbox?

I have set

- Pane 0: `label:Tech`, Panel Title: Tech
- Pane 1: `label:Management`, Panel Title: Management
- Maximum Page size show (10)
- Extra panels positioning: Right side of inbox

Comment: @Rubén: I still see it listed under "Labs".

Comment: @AlE. it's curious that is not available for Spanish latinoamerica, at least I didn't found. Anyway, are you able to use the Multiple Inbox lab? I read that it doesn't work with the "new classic inbox".

Comment: @Rubén: Yeah, seems to work, although I moved to the categorized inbox a long time ago.

Comment: @AlE. Thanks. I took a look again and I found it (i forgot to type the accent of "Múltiple" :$) Also I tried. Looks that it's working fine but requires to uncheck all the optional tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with the following steps

1. Disable multiple inbox under Labs
2. Go back to inbox and click on the little drop down and select classic inbox
3. Go back to labs and enable the multiple inbox again
4. This worked for me and now you can go to the Multiple Inboxes pane and edit your inboxes you would like to view in your mailbox home page

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the labs feature you could use the gmail inbuild functionality
Settings -> Inbox

Change Inbox type to priority Inbox

Inbox sections will appear, edit them to match your needs.

Comment: When I select Priority inbox no inbox sections appear. only when I select important first or any of the others, do these inbox sections appear

Comment: Try going on to important inbox then click the 'customize in Priority Inbox' that should do it

Comment: Yes but I would like to be able to place my mail anywhere on the page and not have this long list of sections in my inbox. Thus 1 in the middle 3 on the right for example.